# Starting Process and identify it later

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduling

Right now i'm programming a cron-like scheduler in c++. My program is able to start jobs at specific times and schedules them correctly.
What leave me troubles is check if a process still exists.

So i have a map JobMap; which is filled with process Handles as keys and Jobs as values. 
How can i bring those two values in relation? I'm stuck at the point that whenever i try GetExitCodeProcess it never returns STILL_ACTIVE. Is it possible to set a unique token/key for a process so i can identify it and bring it in relation with a job?

Any idea would be a great help, thanks a lot!

```
void Cron::CheckRunningJobs()
{
    DatNowObj Today;
    DWORD exitCode = 0;

   // now iterate through the executed jobs and check their state
    for(MC_STL_PTR(MapPtr,JobMap)) //MapPtr is a pointer for my map
    {
        DatStrNowObj Today; //gives actual date
        DWORD exitCode = 0;
        PROT()<<"Job Handle:"<<MapPtr->first <<"Job in Map: "<<MapPtr->second.Job->getDescription()<<endl;

        // store the exit code for later use
        MapPtr->second.exitCode = GetExitCodeProcess(MapPtr->first, &exitCode);
        if(GetExitCodeProcess(MapPtr->first, &exitCode) == STILL_ACTIVE)
        {
            PROT()<<"PROCESS STILL ACTIVE"<<endl;
        }
        else if(GetExitCodeProcess(MapPtr->first, &exitCode) == ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION)
        {
            CloseHandle(MapPtr->first);
            continue;
        }
        else if(MapPtr->second.execTime)
        {

        }
        else if(GetExitCodeProcess(MapPtr->first, &exitCode) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle(MapPtr->first);

            JobMap.erase(MapPtr);

            PROT()<<"Job in Map after Erase: "<<MapPtr->second.Job->getDescription() << "and Map size: " << JobMap.size()<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            PROT()<<"Error:"<<GetLastError()<<endl;
            continue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do a `WaitForSingleObject` on the handle you get form `CreateProcess` (which in your case seems to be `MapPtr->first`).

Comment: MapPtr->first is a HANDLE stored from CreateProcess. Wouldn't WaitForSingleObject block other processes? I mean if i have 2 Jobs which start at the same time.

Comment: It wouldn't block other processes, but your process (in the thread you call it). So you either wait for each in a separate thread, or use a dedicated thread for waiting, that calls `WaitForMultipleObjects` for all "current" handles. The later of course involves some cross thread communication for passing handles of new processes and notifying some other code/thread in your process that (some) process is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx) that *user6545984* linked. You seem to be getting very mixed up here.

`GetExitCodeProcess()` returns a `BOOL` indicating whether the *function* succeeded, not the process. You're trying to compare against that `BOOL` using constants as if it's an `exitCode`. But they're incompatible types. Even if they weren't, I have no idea why you would keep calling the function over and over again!

To get the exit code, you need to pass in an `LPDWORD` pointer to receive it. Call the function *once*, get the two outputs into the *right* variables - one return value, one output argument - and respond to those appropriately.

So, you need to change at least this

```
MapPtr->second.exitCode = GetExitCodeProcess(MapPtr->first, &exitCode);
```

to something like

```
BOOL result = GetExitCodeProcess(MapPtr->first, &MapPtr->second.exitCode);
```

or wherever else you want to store said code - then update all your comparisons to match, and also add comparisons to `result` if you need to.

Comment: +1 @Majid D. L. just make sure that you understand that `GetExitCodeProcess` will return *immediately* if the process is `STILL_ACTIVE`. So either you call your function only from time to time, and doing other stuff in the meantime, or resort to a `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` approach. You don't want to (accidentally) write a "busyloop" that will poll repeatedly for the exit code of processes still running.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps me. I was kinda blind to see it, thought it would return the Exitcode directly.

Comment: @MajidD.L. You're welcome. If this helps you, please upvote. If it answers your question, please mark it as the answer using the tick.

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL WINAPI GetExitCodeProcess(
  _In_  HANDLE  hProcess,
  _Out_ LPDWORD lpExitCode
);
```

It doesn't return exit code directly. Learn more at [GetExitCodeProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It would be worth mentioning in your answer what the returned `BOOL` does: indicates whether the _function_ succeeded.